# How to construct logic from nothing as a step by step procedure?

Tags: logic, axiom

I am thinking of constructing logic from scratch. I tried the `law of thought` as a fresh start but not totally convinced this is a correct way for the following reason:

if `law of identity` is the first, then the first step is `law of identity is true`, where the concept `true` is not defined.

if the `law of excluded middle` is the first, then logical operator `or` is not defined.

if the `law of non-contradiction` is the first, then logical operator `not` and `and` are not defined.

However, on the other hand if I start the logical operators at first. In order to check soundness and completeness of those operators, I have to use the `law of thought`. (If my understanding is correct, at least `law of identity` will be used)

For the last ditch effort, if I define `true/false` as the first step, I cannot envision a way that does not involve equality, which is defined by `law of identity`.

Suppose we have some fundamental things of logic, and we want to put it one piece after another to complete the construction, what is  a possible way that every construction step does not involve the concept after this construction step?

Comment: If you want to star "from scratch" you have first to build language from scratch.

Comment: As your question above clearly shows, you are "building" logic using language. Every human mathematical text uses (natural) language. Can you imagine a different approach?

Comment: You need the basic feature of communication: *meaning* and *rule*. You need counting and you need the [Type–token distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93token_distinction).

Comment: Nohow. To construct something you need something else to construct it from, so "from scratch" won't work. At the basis of any subject there is a handful of fundamental terms that can be related to each other in a circle, but not "constructed from nothing", as you discovered the hard way. What are your "fundamental things of logic" that we are supposed to start from (instead of nothing) to "complete" it?

Comment: I don't know and that's why I am asking it. I have to aware the fact that my ignorance does not imply such thing not exist. No how is really something that I want to have but at this stage not finding a good way to justify the non existence by not using the tool itself.

Comment: Picardi takes truth and falsehood, conditional, variables, predicates, identity, etc., as [primitive notions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_notion) of logic.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking about corresponds with the notion of demonstrative reasoning from Aristotle's "Posterior Analytics." This is effectively expunged in modern studies by the practice of "formalization" which translates natural language statements into symbolic representations through paraphrasing.

What is, in fact, the case is that Aristotle mentions demonstration in the syntactic analysis of "Prior Analytics." Its purpose arises from pedagogical considerations. And, demonstrative reasoning is differentiated from dialectical reasoning. The latter is discussed in his book "Topics." Unfortunately, demonstrative reasoning is characterized in terms of prior and posterior knowledge statements. So, its pedagogical motivation is conflated with epistemology.

In so far as "formalizing" arises from the foundational studies of David Hilbert, it breaks the Aristotelian use cases. Contrary to modern descriptions, Hilbert explains that "formal axiomatics" is to be distinguished from "axiomatics" generally. And, a particular presupposition prioritizes universal quantification over existential quantification. This is significant because Aristotle describes the natural numbers in terms of prior and posterior elements. First-order accounts of natural numbers assume that all numbers exist simultaneously. Aristotle's account of prior and posterior knowledge claims for demonstrations is found in the same passage of "Categories" in which his account of natural numbers can be found.

Formal axiomatics breaks Aristotle.

To accomplish what you ask, you will have to begin with a geometric metamathematics, 16 denoting symbols intended to serve as logical constants for propositional connectivity, and 5 additional denoting symbols which may be taken as 4 quantifier mnemonics and a mnemonic for absurdity. These numbers are not random. They correspond to the projective plane on 21 symbols. A mathematician named Curtis situated the vector space GF(2)^4 into an affine subplane of this projective plane. If one correlates the 16 basic Boolean functions with this vector space, negation and de Morgan conjugation become collineations in the plane.

One can then use standard truth tables to formulate 4096 functional stipulations that convey compositionality. When the stipulations are summarized by collation into 16 Cayley tables, the usual truth tables are recovered as subtables. This method requires an understanding of function application as found in the lambda calculus since the denoting  symbols in a functional context will accept themselves as arguments.

This is how you start from nothing.

The Cayley tables are important. In ordinary mathematics the transition from algebraic structures to metric structures involves attaching a set to an inner product space. This is called a Euclidean point space. If, as described above, one is merely using a vector space, one obtains an affine space. The mapping involved goes from the Cartesian product of a given set to the inner product space or  the vector space. The Cayley tables each contain 256 elements, the cardinality of a 16x16 Cartesian product. The Cayley table for exclusive disjunction has the needed correlation with the vector space elements. Moreover, it is the only one that does.

With regard to mutual exclusion, using the vector space GF(2)^1 for a 2-symbol system will yield,

f(a,a) = 0
f(b,b) = 0
f(a,b) = 1
f(b,a) = 1

Consequently, it is numerical difference rather than "self-identity" which corresponds with truth as it is represented in Boolean arithmetic. Obviously, one can use 'T' and 'F' for the 2-symbol system, whence the exclusive disjunction is the natural expression of mutual exclusion with respect to ordinary mathematics.

The fact that one can use inner product spaces is not trivial. In 1999 Pavicic and Megill showed that propositional logic is not categorical. A 6-element ortholattice is involved with the non-Boolean model. Among other things, inner products convey orthogonality. In the theory of ortholattices, the orthocomplement in a Boolean lattice is negation. So, truth tables speak to the affine structure, but, the free Boolean lattice on 2 generators is also an ortholattice on 4 atoms.

The two ways of understanding numerical difference yield two models of propositional logic.

One may object to this use of geometry.  But, the standard combinatorial investigation of mathematical logic invokes "sensible impressions" of written symbols as its ground. Because Curtis used a 4x4 array for his constructions, one can build the syntactic realization of these methods from tetrahedra with labeled vertices and the fact that the smallest non-isomorphic idempotent quasigroups are of order 4. All of this can be understood as arising from a priori experience.

Once one has propositional connectivity, one has a NAND connective with which to develop a propositional logic.

With regard to the law of identity, it is not mandated by Tarski's semantic conception of truth. However, the use of logic dictates that the first axiomatic assertions involving non-propositional logic introduce the sign of equality. The difference between Aristotle and Hilbert strongly suggests two systems. One system begins with an assertion relating equality to the existential quantifier. The other begins with an assertion relating equality to the universal quantifier. Both systems must assert the substitutivity interpretation of equality (with respect to itself) as the second formula. The non-propositional inference rules must conform with these statements. The one emphasizing the universal quantifier uses first-order inference rules.

In his landmark paper on semantics, Tarski is clear about its inapplicability to systems that build languages through symbol introduction. In his work on set theory, Quine speaks of introducing the membership relation in a specific manner. However, he fails to think about this in the context of a formal proof. This manner of symbol introduction is addressed in Kleene's "Introduction to Metamathematics." But, it is directed at the eliminability of definite descriptions. So, while Kleene acknowledges that the procedure of symbol introduction generates a sequence of language signatures, he never considers what must be involved when one is using the procedure to build language signatures.

Since Kleene speaks of "eliminability," the signatures obtained by this procedure must be understood with respect to eliminability and non-eliminability. The system using first-order inference can apply first-order model theory at any step. But, the usual notion of obtaining a signature through "formalizing" does not apply.

The other system is understood with respect to Skolem's criticism of Russell's description theory. In modern parlance, it is an application of negative free logic absent a semantics. The semantics are problematic because the inference rules use the sign of equality to convey "is defined" as those familiar with recursion theory. What "exists" arises from explicit existential assertions and inductive formulas. Its relationship to what Skolem called the inductive mode of reasoning arises from the fact that the non-eliminable relations inductively generate terms in the sense described by Moschovakis in his book on elementary induction on abstract structures.

Although this procedure can be made to work, it can, at most provide universal preambles to formal derivations. It cannot be a replacement for the usual methods of mathematical logic.

If you would like to see some of this ping

scilogic01

xemaps

com

You can figure out the punctuation. I doubt, however, that you will appreciate the combinatorial complexity of such a system.

Comment: Really nice explanation. However. The entire purpose of this practice is for education purpose. (Make the educational content complete while easy to understand). Given such effort, it's contradicts the intention to make an easy logic introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Since your purpose is educational, let me strongly suggest that you personally obtain a copy of "The Trivium" by Sister Miriam McGlinn. This is the best book of a modern character I have found that explains logic in the context of its origin in the liberal arts. It will give you a basis for assessing how to teach logic meaningfully.

Modern conceptions of logic that are useful for maintaining a technological society are the product of skepticism. Skepticism cannot be a foundation for anything. So, it has no "starting point" in any reasonable sense. The intractable nature of first principles means that one  can always undermine any asserted first definition. Although Aristotle never makes this particular claim, his book Topics observes how any counterexample undermines a proposed definition. By his own account, Topics is the study of argumentation from common beliefs. This can be used harmlessly in the dialectical comparison of alternatives. But, more often than not, it is employed in the guise of "I do not believe THAT!"

In certain respects, the modern recursion theory that gives us modern computation is a consequence of this behavior. Cantor's analysis of trigonometric series led to a system of iterated labels requiring a counting method extending beyond counting with whole numbers. Objections to these completed infinities led to philosophies of mathematics that disallow such ideas (I do not believe THAT!). Those which do the least harm to ordinary mathematics insist that one must respect how any natural language use involves only finitely many symbols at any given point in time. Since human beings had been referred to as "computers" before the advent of their electronic replacements, Turing's model of computation is based on this observation of finite use at particular points in time as it applies to flesh and blood computation.

What this means for logic is that 'true' and 'false' are spellings rather than meaningful words. Along similar lines, the usual logic words like "and" and "not" are meaningless.

It is sometimes difficult to look at the world and see people screaming meaninglessly at one another while being "logical" at every turn.

The modern skeptical argument is to be found in the work of David Hume. The attempt to recover some sense of objective truth as a response to Hume is given by Immanuel Kant. But, Kant's attempt to base objective truth on the relationship of mathematics to subjective experience had been met with skepticism on many fronts (I do not believe THAT!). With respect to modern logic, the criticism of mathematics by Bernhard Bolzano is probably most relevant, although having little influence at the time. The literature typically attributes a belief in Euclidean geometry as a principal reason for the failure of Kant's views. But a translation by William Ewald has shown that Kant actually called for the development of alternative geometries. Mostly, it is probably the general belief that mathematics has some association with material reality which prevented others from accepting the Kantian view.

Needless to say, Kant's critics generated a great deal of syntax (remember, logic is meaningless) intended to show that Kant had erred. Few, if any, every addressed the problem of skepticism that motivated Kant. So, despite the rhetoric, Kant is not entirely overturned. What I have just stated is acknowledged in the papers of the respected logician George Boolos. And, in so far as the syntactic nature of modern logic is traced to David Hilbert's proof theory, Hilbert did not deny Kant as others had. He merely observed that Kant's application of a priori sensible intuition had been too broad. The modern distinction between syntax and semantics rests on starting with linguistic symbols as mere sensible impressions.

The problem with your assumption that these things can be taught in a simple manner is that the spellings 'true' and 'false' will be assumed to refer to "truth" and "falsity" by your students. For the sake of usefulness you will try to teach modern notions of logic without addressing the use cases of which Aristotle had spoken.  And, most importantly, you will not have addressed the question of "To whom is this modern logic most useful?" In other words, are you training or are you educating?

Within the philosophical literature there is an augmentation to the dichotomy between syntax and semantics which is called pragmatics. This distinction is credited to Rudolph Carnap, and, it is meant to address the relationship of language elements to language users. Unfortunately, it usually assumes that there are no disputes in the foundations of mathematics. But, its very existence indicates that the initial teaching of logic ought not be directed at furthering the skepticism discussed above.

What you might consider is to direct your teaching of logic to the study of doxastic logic first. Wikipedia has an entry on this. Then, logic is presented intensionally before moving on to the extensional and quantitative logic of mathematics that has produced paradoxes and promoted skepticism. I doubt, however, that your time constraints will allow this.

So, start with Venn diagrams, Euler diagrams, and truth tables. Then say a prayer for your students.

Comment: Wow, now I get it. I would say skepticism are super cheating in the sense of creating something from nothing. Really appreciate for this detailed answer!